# Jhipster: Mircoservice not registering with jhipster-registry

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I created a microservice using jhipster (version of generator-jhipster is 5.0.1). It contains the following components:

- Microservice1
- Jhipster Registry
- Keycloak as auth server

If I start the microservice using the generated docker-compose config (app.yml), it starts all the components without any issue.

But if I start the components individually using their respective docker-compose configurations
eg:

`docker-compose -f jhipster-registry.yml up -d 
 docker-compose -f postgres.yml up -d 
 docker-compose -f keycloak.yml up -d`

then I see the following exception in the microservice.

```
    2018-09-14T05:56:33.860533100Z 
2018-09-14 05:56:33.859  WARN 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-09-14 05:56:33.859 ERROR 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MS1/ms1:9d9ed2e17bb03d945b64e18e4d49ba5f - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
2018-09-14T05:56:33.860794800Z 
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1471)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1438)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-14T05:56:33.861228500Z 
2018-09-14 05:56:34.735 ERROR 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
2018-09-14T05:56:34.736291200Z 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
... 27 common frames omitted
2018-09-14T05:56:34.737447400Z 
2018-09-14 05:56:34.738  WARN 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-09-14 05:56:34.739 ERROR 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MS1/ms1:9d9ed2e17bb03d945b64e18e4d49ba5f - was unable to send heartbeat!
2018-09-14T05:56:34.741411800Z 
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-09-14T05:56:34.742030100Z
```

The microservice is unable to register with the registry. Can you please let me know what the reason is and also the fix.

- Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you start with `app.yml`, your microservice waits 30 seconds for the registry to start up (`JHIPSTER_SLEEP` env var).  Try waiting before starting your app locally, make sure the registry is accessible first

Comment: I did start the jhipster registry first. Ensured the delay and then started micro service. But still the same.

Comment: Did you make sure the registry started by visiting its user interface in the browser?

Comment: Yes the registry was up and I could see the UI in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While debugging (using remote debug in eclipse) I found that while using separate docker compose files, service was trying to connect to localhost whereas single docker compose file case service was trying to connect to jhipster-registry.

**Reason:**
There are some minor differences for jhipster registry configuration in docker compose files.

app.yml uses docker-config folder in central-config folder whereas jhipster-registry uses localhost-config folder in central-config folder.

**app.yml**

```
jhipster-registry:
    extends:
        file: jhipster-registry.yml
        service: jhipster-registry
    environment:
        - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/docker-config/
```

**central-server-config/docker-config/application.yml**

```
eureka:
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka/
```

====================================

**jhipster-registry.yml**

```
jhipster-registry:
    image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.3.0
    ....
    environment:
        - ...
        - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/localhost-config/
```

**central-server-config/localhost-config/application.yml**

```
eureka:
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Making jhipster-registry.yml to use docker-config folder value instead of localhost-config folder value helped in solving this issue.

**Note:-** no idea what role "native search location" property plays here and how and why it impacts the service as this is a jhipster registry config property. I will update when I figure it out.